# Postgres Fails to create trigger function; 'syntax error near RETURN'

Tags: postgresql, triggers, ddl

I am a postgres noob and would like to create a trigger function for my admins table.
I am following an example that is online, have checked for similar questions and tried various online examples but i am still stuck.

I have a table **admins**

```
CREATE TABLE admins (
admin_name      varchar(15) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
password        text NOT NULL,
telephone       varchar(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
email           varchar(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
added           timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
name            varchar(30) NOT NULL,
active          boolean DEFAULT true     
);
```

And an audit table **aud_admins**

```
CREATE TABLE aud_admins (
admin_name      varchar(15) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
password        text NOT NULL,
telephone       varchar(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
email           varchar(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
added           timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
name            varchar(30) NOT NULL,
active          boolean DEFAULT true,
updated         timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
func            varchar(15)  NOT NULL     
);
```

- I'm trying to create a stored trigger function to update the **aud_admins** table whenever there is a change but have failed woefully

This is my trigger function code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.audit_admins()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN 
IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
    INSERT INTO aud_admins (admin_name,password,telephone,email,added,name,active,func) VALUES (OLD.admin_name,OLD.password,OLD.telephone,OLD.email,OLD.added,OLD.name,OLD.active,PG_OP)
    RETURN OLD;
ENDIF;
IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
     INSERT INTO aud_admins (admin_name,password,telephone,email,added,name,active,func) VALUES (NEW.admin_name,NEW.password,NEW.telephone,NEW.email,NEW.added,NEW.name,NEW.active,PG_OP)
     RETURN NEW;
ENDIF;
IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
    INSERT INTO aud_admins (admin_name,password,telephone,email,added,name,active,func) VALUES (OLD.admin_name,OLD.password,OLD.telephone,OLD.email,OLD.added,OLD.name,OLD.active,PG_OP)
    RETURN NEW;
ENDIF;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Every time I run it I get this error

```
**ERROR:  syntax error at or near "RETURN"
  LINE 7:         RETURN OLD;**
```

Basic runtime specs:

> Postgres 9.5 on
>   Ubuntu 16.04
>   with pgAdmin3

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your insert statements are missing the trailing semi-colon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `INSERT` statements are not terminated with semi-colons. Try updating to the following:

```
IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
    INSERT INTO aud_admins (admin_name,password,telephone,email,added,name,active,func) 
    SELECT OLD.admin_name,OLD.password,OLD.telephone,OLD.email,OLD.added,OLD.name,OLD.active,PG_OP;
    RETURN OLD;
END IF;
IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
     INSERT INTO aud_admins (admin_name,password,telephone,email,added,name,active,func) 
     SELECT NEW.admin_name,NEW.password,NEW.telephone,NEW.email,NEW.added,NEW.name,NEW.active,PG_OP;
     RETURN NEW;
END IF;
IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
    INSERT INTO aud_admins (admin_name,password,telephone,email,added,name,active,func) 
    SELECT OLD.admin_name,OLD.password,OLD.telephone,OLD.email,OLD.added,OLD.name,OLD.active,PG_OP;
    RETURN NEW;
END IF;
```

Updated the inserts, I think you need to actually `INSERT` using a `SELECT`. Give the modified code above a try.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response [@gmiley](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3885008/gmiley) , however when I do that I get the error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ENDIF"
            LINE 9: ENDIF;`

Comment: Made a change to use `SELECT` with the `INSERT`. Give that a try. That would be the only other thing I could think of that might make a difference judging by the error you are getting.

Comment: @ianmin2 `END IF;`, with space.

Comment: Good catch, don't know how I missed that too. Funny thing is, at one point I was suggesting switching to `CASE` statement, which would have fixed the problem as well.

Comment: @Abelisto, Thanks for your comment, but I realise that with my version of postgres it works even with spaces.